# Should one install cgal 4.12 via packages or manually? (ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: ubuntu, boost, cgal

If the package-based approach to installing CGAL 4.12 on ubuntu (on the order of a minute) provides the same functionality of a manual installation (a day-long effort)  it would be good to know.

To manually build cgal 4.12, I assembled the prerequisite codes. This is a significant task, but I anticipated some advantage relative to "package installations".

Aside: My system already had a boost directory /usr/include/boost with 1.6.2, which I had installed a while back for some reason, using a package. (This is relevant to the warning messages introduced below.)

In order to get cmake to work for 4.12, I had to edit CMakeCache.txt to look for the directory /usr/include/boost_1_67_0. After I did that, cmake finished. It seems to have found the boost info needed.

But cmake emitted a couple of scary warnings. They are below.

cmake also emitted the message:

Configuring libCGAL_Qt5
-- libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies: Qt5OpenGL Qt5Svg Qt5 cannot be configured.
-- Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt5' detected

Because of these messages, I did not build cgal.

Instead, I installed cgal via packages (apt-get).

My question is: Is there a significant advantage to building cgal 
manually for me to figure out how to fix the warnings (if needed)? Or should I work with the package installed versions?

I can also see the possibility of have versions installed in differing 
locations . . .

Thank you in advance:

Tim

Warning messages from cmake (each was printed twice):

~~~~~~~~~~~~

CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:771 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106700
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:875 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1519 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupCGAL_CoreDependencies.cmake:59 (find_package)
  src/CGAL_Core/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)

~~~~~~~~~

Make Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:771 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106700
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:875 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1519 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupCGAL_CoreDependencies.cmake:84 (find_package)
  src/CGAL_Core/CMakeLists.txt:14 (CGAL_setup_CGAL_Core_dependencies)

Comment: You can use the pre-built packages just fine.

Comment: Marc: Thank you for the feedback. Is there a description of the optional software packages, and cmake variables used to build the package? Tim

Comment: `apt showsrc cgal` shows the build dependencies. `apt-get source cgal` gets you the sources, and you can look at `cgal-4.12/debian/rules` and neighboring files for the exact build recipe.

Answer (score 0):

While my original question remains unanswered, I managed to complete a manual install of CGAL 4.12 on ununtu 17.10.

I found a post by Laurent Rineau (CGAL) from 10/5/2017 that contains a few qt libraries needed to configure CGAL (4.11) on ubuntu (17.10?). I felt lucky, and used apt-get to install: libqt5svg5-dev, qtscript5-dev,libqt5opengl5-dev.

I then was able to make the libraries: CGAL, CGAL_core, CGAL_ImageIO, and CGAL_Qt5.

(Along the way, I installed Qt 5.3 - mentioned in the CGAL manual installation instructions, which didn't help, so I removed it.)

While the warnings wrt boost (shown in my original post above) were again emitted during cmake, I will push forward.

Tim